# AutoMapper Threading Issue (Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, thread-safety, automapper

I'm not sure if I have a threading issue here or not.  On the page load I am executing two Ajax requests to load some additional data from a third party API.  Here is what each method looks like that gets called:

```
private List<CaseCommentModel> GetCaseCommentModels(string caseId) {
    var comments = CaseService.GetAllCaseCommentsByCaseId(caseId);

    Mapper.Reset();
    Mapper.CreateMap<CrmCaseComment, CaseCommentModel>();

    var caseCommentModels = Mapper.Map<List<CrmCaseComment>, List<CaseCommentModel>>(comments);

    return caseCommentModels;
}

private List<CaseAttachmentModel> GetCaseAttachmentModels(string caseId) {
    var attachments = AttachmentService.GetAttachmentsByParentId(caseId);

    Mapper.Reset();
    Mapper.CreateMap<CrmAttachment, CaseAttachmentModel>();

    var caseAttachmentModels = Mapper.Map<List<CrmAttachment>, List<CaseAttachmentModel>>(attachments);

    return caseAttachmentModels;
}
```

Sometimes both responses succeed.  But, if I refresh the page, sometimes one will fail with the following exception:

`Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping`

I can go from both requests succeeding to one failing without making any code changes; all it takes is a refresh of the page.  Is this a threading issue or am I using the mapper incorrectly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should Create a Mapping only **once** per application life time. So, move each specific `CreateMap` to app start.

The problem you are experiencing is probably related to the race to do the mapping before the other thread calls `Mapper.Reset()`

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you have a threading issue and you are misusing the Automapper configuration.
From the Automapper [getting started page](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started):

> If you're using the static Mapper method, configuration only needs to
>   happen once per AppDomain. That means the best place to put the
>   configuration code is in application startup, such as the Global.asax
>   file for ASP.NET applications. Typically, the configuration
>   bootstrapper class is in its own class, and this bootstrapper class is
>   called from the startup method.

So you shouldn't have `Mapper.CreateMap` inside the controller actions move them to common place and execute them once.

Or if you do need dynamic mapping configuration don't use the static `Mapper` instead of build the config and the engine "by hand":

```
var config = 
    new ConfigurationStore(new TypeMapFactory(), MapperRegistry.AllMappers());
config.CreateMap<CrmCaseComment, CaseCommentModel>();
var engine = new MappingEngine(config);
var caseCommentModels = 
    engine.Map<List<CrmCaseComment>, List<CaseCommentModel>>(comments);
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across a **threading issue** and would like to share my findings.

In my application in the ***WCF Service Constructor*** I called the **AutoMapperRegistry. Configure ()** to create the Mappings for the auto mapper.

From the ***MVC controller*** I call the service by calling the **singleton object of the WCF service**.

The ***actual issue*** is from the **web client** I actually **called asyncrounusly two of the controller methods** so that both communicated to the service and returns the result. The moment i **changed the first method to Async false in the problem was resolved**.

**Reason** 
When both methods are called async the **race condition occurs** and once in a while that is resolved by it self sometimes this threading issue is created as a result the above exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have a threading issue and the best solutionis (in my opinion) is to stop using static API from AutoMapper.

I propose you configure automapper in follwoing way: 
// IoC registration (Autofac in my case)

```
builder
    .Register(c => new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
        cfg.AddProfile<AutoMapperProfile>();
    }))
    .SingleInstance();
builder
    .Register(c => c.Resolve<MapperConfiguration>().CreateMapper())
    .As<AutoMapper.IMapper>();
```

Please note that I create MapperConfiguration as single instance.
Class AutoMapperProfile.cs contains configuration of automapper:

```
class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
{
    public AutoMapperProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Source, Destination>();
        // usual configurations...
    }
}
```